# IEnumerable can't convert to IQueryable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable

Until now, I have a .net 4.7 library in which I use IQuery in this mode:

```
IQueryable<MyType> myIQueryable = mySource;

if(paramIsNew != null)
{
    myIQueryable = myIQueryable.where(x => x.IsNew == paramIsNew);
}
```

And so on for more parameters and conditions.

However, now I am trying to convert this library to a .net standard library, but I am getting the error that I can´t convert an IEnumerable to IQueryable, it exists and explicit conversion.

I don't see the problem really and how to solve it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Why would you think that it should be an `IEnumerable`?  That would perform the operations in memory, rather than in an underlying data source, which is likely to be preferable.

Comment: What line is this error coming in on? Looking at that code the most likely option I see is that mySource is `IEnumerable<MyType>` which is causing the error... It may not be but you need to confirm the details.

Comment: Either `myIQueryable.where(x => x.IsNew == paramIsNew);` should not compile or it is calling a custom method written by you, C# is case sensitive and the actual method is `Where` not `where`, so please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually compiles with corrected capitialization or includes your custom `where` extension method. Also the MCVE needs to include how you get `mySource`

Comment: @PatrickHofman There *is* no cast in the code, so the non-existent cast obviously can't be invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `Queryable` class and so queryable-specific extension methods (like `Where`), are not part of default .NET Standard libraries. So you use `Enumerable.Where` extension method, which returns `IEnumerable`. Your `myIQueryable` is of type `IQueryable` hence you are getting compiler error. You need to install `System.Linq.Queryable` nuget package, then your code with compile.